# How to verify my calculated amplitude under gauge invariance structure?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, feynman-diagrams, ward-identity

I calculated the Compton amplitude of three diagrams but how can I verify it under gauge invariance structure?
$$
{\cal A} = 2 e^2 \left[ \frac{ p_3 \cdot \epsilon_1 p_2 \cdot \epsilon_4^* }{ p_2 \cdot p_4 } - \frac{ p_2 \cdot \epsilon_1 p_3 \cdot \epsilon_4^*}{ p_2 \cdot p_1 } + \epsilon_1 \cdot \epsilon_4^* \right]
$$

Comment: On this site all math is expected to be in MathJax. Scans of handwriting are not considered acceptable. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial.

Comment: Thank you so much 

Comment: Writing four 4-vectors next to each other doesn’t mean anything.

Comment: Oh no the p1 and p4 are the initial and final photon momenta and p2 and p4 is for electron and of course the epsilon is the polarization for photons.

Comment: I was referring to your omission of the scalar products, which Prahar added when he did the MathJax for you. You mean $p_2$ and $p_3$ for the electron.

Answer (score 1):

Gauge invariance requires that the amplitude vanishes if you replace the polarization with its corresponding momentum. If we replace $\epsilon_4 \to p_4$, we get
\begin{align}
{\cal A} &\to 2 e^2 \left[ \frac{ p_3 \cdot \epsilon_1 p_2 \cdot p_4 }{ p_2 \cdot p_4 } - \frac{ p_2 \cdot \epsilon_1 p_3 \cdot p_4}{ p_2 \cdot p_1 } + \epsilon_1 \cdot p_4 \right]\\
&=  2 e^2 ( p_3 + p_4 - p_2 ) \cdot \epsilon_1 \\
&=  2 e^2 p_1 \cdot \epsilon_1 \\
&= 0
\end{align}
In the second line, I have used the fact that $p_3 \cdot p_4 = p_1 \cdot p_2$ which is implied by momentum conservation. In the third, we have again used momentum conservation, $p_1 + p_2 = p_3 + p_4$.

You can try to verify gauge invariance by also replacing $\epsilon_1 \to p_1$.